# How to parse XML and insert content into HTML form using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, xml, insert, parsing

I have a simple XMl file with image tags:

XML:

```
<img src="images/image1" alt="My Image 1" />
<img src="images/image2" alt="My Image 2" />
<img src="images/image3" alt="My Image 3" />
<img src="images/image4" alt="My Image 4" />
```

I need to insert this content ("src" attrib) inside a `<div>` tag in my HTML form.

HTML:

```
<div id="photos">
</div>
```

Does anyone know how this can be done using **jQuery** ?

Thanks in Advance.

H.

Comment: Why store that in an xml file? It's just html.

Answer (score 2):

Since your xml file contains valid html markup, why don't you just jam it into your div directly?

```
$('#photos').load('TheFile.xml')
```

Comment: Short and sweet, but assumes that the XML file contains just the img tags. If it actually contains a complete XML document, then the solution posted by @easement would be preferable.

Answer (score 1):

what about something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function imageData() {
    //first we need to load the XML data for that detail row
    //if the function is a success it will call the function called processDetail
    $.ajax({
       type: "GET",
       url: "PATH_TO_XML_GOES_HERE",
       dataType: "xml",
       success: getImages
     });
}

function getImages(xml) {
    //this function gets the results from the xml file
    //and inserts them in to the boxes
    $(xml).find("img").each(function()   {
        $("#photos").append(this);
    });
}
</script>
```

hacked form here: http://www.getdowntonight.co.uk/2009/08/using-xml-in-your-jquery-to-populate-input-boxes/

may not work, but looks like it gets you on your way.